# scrapy.Request(url, recall), the recall can not be successfully called

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I wrote a very small scrapy project, but problems occur when I ran the project using scrapy crawl command. As shown in the picture: the first print can successfully print the url which means the scrapy.Request(url,self.parse_dir_content) should be successfully executed. however the second print sentence did not print anything to the screen.That is weird. Anyone can help? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: please share your logs (with stats), I suspect this is mostly because of a filtered request.

Comment: The first command just yields a `Request`, it doesn't mean that the request gets processed. Without knowing any other details, one reason could be that the request gets filtered as an offsite request (based on `allowed_domains`). But let's see, share logs please.

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: Impossible to look at your issue without looking at logs. Also please don't post code screenshot. Add the code to your question

Comment: Thank you all very much. You are right, the request gets filterd based on allowed_domains. It has different domains as the the main domain. I did not pay attention to this. Thank you for your willing to help. And also the suggestion on how to ask question on this site. Thank you